# PHP echo and onmouseover

Tags: echo, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have this HTML code and it works perfect:

`<a href="www.link.com"><img onmouseover="this.src='http://www.example.com.img1.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.example.com.img2.jpg';" src="http://www.example.com.img2.jpg" alt="ALT Text" class="img-responsive"/></br></a>`

I want to add this code in PHP and replace the link and image urls with this variables: $link, $image_src1 and $image_src2.

I tried this code:

`<a href=".$link."><img onmouseover="this.src='.$image_src1.';" onmouseout="this.src='.$image_src2.';" src=".$image_src2." alt="ALT Text" class="img-responsive"/></br></a>`

I think I can not manage how to use quotes, because of this, I am getting an error.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$link = 'http://www.google.com';
$image_src1 = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148766.svg";
$image_src2 = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149147.svg";
echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><img onmouseover="this.src='.$image_src1.';" onmouseout="this.src='.$image_src2.';" src="'.$image_src2.'" alt="ALT Text" class="img-responsive"/></br></a>';
```

But you really need to look in your code logic, for mouseover/out. You can achieve same logic using CSS `:hover` property in simple and elegant way.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. Some elements are displayed as a text. See a screenshot here http://nimb.ws/FUq71u

Comment: Please upload your demo code somewhere, then I'll look what's wrong in it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Muhammad I managed it to work with CSS and :hover

This is my code in case someone needs it:

```
    echo '<div class="effect">';
    echo '<img class="image" src="'.$image_src.'';
    echo '<img class="image hover" src="'.$image_src2.'';
    echo '</div>';
```

And the CSS:

```
.effect img.image{
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.effect:hover img.image{
display:none;
}
.effect img.hover{
display:none;
}
.effect:hover img.hover{
display:block;
}
```